# rails how to write a query with join table and conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two tables, **Category** and **Product**

```
  create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title", limit: 100, null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title", limit: 150, null: false
    t.decimal "price", precision: 15, scale: 2, default: "0.0", null: false
    t.text "description"
    t.bigint "category_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "color"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.json "attachments"
    t.index ["category_id"], name: "index_products_on_category_id"
  end
```

In my search form a user can enter a keyword that could match either:

- product title
- product color
- product description
- product color

**Also it should find by the product's category title.**

In my product controller I have that method:

```
def filter_products
  return if params[:query].blank?
  @products = Product.joins(:category).where('lower(categories.title) LIKE ?', "%#{params[:query][:keyword]}%")
  @products = Product.where('lower(title) LIKE ?', "%#{params[:query][:keyword]}%")
      .or(Product.where('lower(description) LIKE ?', "%#{params[:query][:keyword]}%"))
      .or(Product.where('lower(color) LIKE ?', "%#{params[:query][:keyword]}%"))
end
```

When I search a product by its category it returns nothing

It returns what expected if I remove this line:

```
 @products = Product.where('lower(title) LIKE ?', "%#{params[:query][:keyword]}%")
    .or(Product.where('lower(description) LIKE ?', "%#{params[:query][:keyword]}%"))
    .or(Product.where('lower(color) LIKE ?', "%#{params[:query][:keyword]}%"))
```

As it's not possible to use **joins** with **or** in the query...

How should I change my method to return either by product category title or by product (title, description, color)?

Comment: The third line in your filter_products method overwrites the @products variable you have declared in line 2 every time. You need to chain the scope `@products = @products.where('lower(title) LIKE ?', "%#{params[:query][:keyword]}%")`.

Comment: You should also note that `.joins` creates a LEFT INNER JOIN which will not return rows that do not have any matches in the joined table. If you want to return products with no category you need to use `.left_outer_joins`. https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/03/24/support-for-left-outer-joins-in-rails-5.html

Comment: You should really consider using ransack Gem. That makes your searching life a hell of a lot easier! https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack

Comment: Why not combine them into 1 query? Something like `.where('lower(categories.title) LIKE ? OR lower(description) LIKE ? ', "%#{params[:query][:keyword]}%", "%#{params[:query][:keyword]}%")`

Comment: it's not possible to use join and or in a same query

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, the second query line override @products variable.

Even you dont override the @products variable, Rails will put a "and" SQL operator between your first and second query line in this case. A more clear way you can do is write raw SQL where clauses joined with 'or' operator

The code will be

```
cols = ["`categories`.`title` LIKE :query","`products`.`title` LIKE :query", "`products`.`description` LIKE :query", "`products`.`position` LIKE :query"]

@products = Product.joins(:category).where(cols.join(" OR "), query: "%#{{params[:query][:keyword]}%")
```

which is much more clear and less code.

Comment: that doesn't make the job, it can't find  products where category title is "anything"

Comment: what do you mean by anything? Can you give a data example?

Comment: A category title can be "anything", `shirt`, `pants`, `dogs`, `cat`
I want to return product where category title could be `shirt'

Comment: @NEL it will fulfill your requirement. You seem to be confused somewhere.